# Iframe problem in aspx

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add this iframe to my Aspx page and I'm trying to set the "src" attribute to the page I want with few url parameters. Any idea?

```
<iframe
     src='<%# "FileUpload.aspx?FolderLevel1=a1&FolderLevel2=" + Session["level2"] %>' 
     visible="true" scrolling="no" height="100px" width="400px" frameborder="0" 
     id="I1" name="I1">
</iframe>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `<%#` unless you're performing a databinding action. This should probably be:

```
src='FileUpload.aspx?FolderLevel1=a1&FolderLevel2=<%=Session["level2"]%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: `src='FileUpload.aspx?FolderLevel1=a1&FolderLevel2=<% =Session["level2"] %>`

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple to handle

string videoname;
 videoname= "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoname+"?autoplay=1";

```
Literal1.Text = " <iframe id=\"iframe\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"" + videoname+ "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```